# Is it possible to access the Catalog window programmatically in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, catalog-window

Specifically, I would like to get the selected object, similar to the way you do in ArcCatalog through `IGxDialog.SelectedObject`.

Is there a way to do this?

So far I can get the Catalog DockableWindow but am stumped from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some experimenting, I found that the answer is surprisingly simple - from version 10 on, the ArcMap application object ([esriArcMap.Application](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ApplicationClass_Class/000t00000002000000/)) also implements [IGxApplication](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGxApplication_Interface/0015000000nm000000/), besides the expected [IMxApplication](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v000000zr000000).

This means you can easily access [IGxApplication.SelectedObject](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/SelectedObject_Property/0015000000p3000000/) and work with the catalog in other ways, just like you would in ArcCatalog as usual.